# Getting Null Pointer Exception with Factory Method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, factory-pattern

I am trying to implement the Factory Pattern/Method to create a new class but I keep getting a Null Pointer exception. I have stepped through the code and I can't seem to work out what it is.

```
public class RandomEnemy {

SpaceShipFactory theFactory;
private ArrayList<SpaceShip> enemyList;

public RandomEnemy(){
    setFactory(new SpaceShipFactory());
}

public void createRandomEnemy(int i){
    SpaceShip s;
    s = this.theFactory.createShip(i);
    enemyList.add(s);
}


public void setFactory(SpaceShipFactory theFactory){
    this.theFactory = theFactory;
}


}
```

And the Factory Class:

```
public class SpaceShipFactory {

public SpaceShip createShip(int i){
    SpaceShip s = null;


    if(i == 1){
        s = new SpaceShip(QuickLoad("battlecruiser"), 0, 0, 256, 256);
        System.out.println("Result is battlecruiser");
    }
    else if(i == 2){
        s = new SpaceShip(QuickLoad("battleshooter"), 0, 0, 256, 256);
        System.out.println("Result is battleshooter");
    }
    else if(i == 3){
        s = new SpaceShip(QuickLoad("battlestar"), 0, 0, 256, 256);
        System.out.println("Result is battlestar");
    }


    return s;
}
}
```

When `enemyList.add(s);` is run I get a Null Pointer Exception. Any ideas why this is happening? I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: initialize your list

Comment: You have to initialize enemyList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never initialize `enemyList`.

You need a `enemyList = new ArrayList<Enemy>` somewhere.

An additional note: using `int` variables as [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) is not a good idea. Use a custom `enum` (which could also contain many ship specific data to avoid having a factory at all), for example:

```
enum ShipType
{
  BATTLE_STAR("battlestar"),
  BATTLE_CRUISER(battlecruiser"),
  BATTLE_SHOOTER("battleshooter",

  public final String name;

  private ShipType(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

class SpaceShip
{
  ShipType type;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Such a simple thing - I knew it. Thanks for your help. I'll look into a custom enum - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all enemyList is not initialised. And if i value is not among {1,2,3} you are returning 's' which is reference variable of  SpaceShip and which is not instantiated.